# Let F$(x,y,z)=(xy,yz,xz)$ and $S=\{(x,y,z):x^2+y^2\le1,0\le z\le1\}$. Compute $\iint_{\partial S}\text{F}\cdot \text{n}dA$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification, multiple-integral, orientation

$\def\hl#1#2{\bbox[#1,1px]{#2}}
\def\box#1#2#3#4#5{\color{#2}{\bbox[0px, border: 2px solid #2]{\hl{#3}{\color{white}{\color{#3}{\boxed{\underline{\large\color{#1}{\text{#4}}}\\\color{#1}{#5}\\}}}}}}}
\def\verts#1{\left\vert#1\right\vert}
\def\Verts#1{\left\Vert#1\right\Vert}
\def\pra#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\R{\mathbb{R}}
\def\N{\mathbb{N}}
\def\Z{\mathbb{Z}}$
$\box{black}{black}{}
{Question}
{\text{Let F$(x,y,z)=(xy,yz,xz)$ and $S=\{(x,y,z):x^2+y^2\le1,0\le z\le1\}$}\\
\text{$(a)$ Compute $\iint_{\partial S}\text{F}\cdot \text{n}dA$, where $\partial S$ is oriented outwards, without using }\\
\text{$\hspace{3.5ex}$any theorems.}\\
\text{$(b)$ Compute $\iint_{\partial S}\text{F}\cdot \text{n}dA$ using divergence theorem}}$

**My attempts**

$(a)$ Consider union of $3$ surfaces such that $S_{\text{top}}\cup S_{\text{side}}\cup S_{\text{bottom}}=\partial S$ i.e.
\begin{align}
&S_{\text{top}}=\{(x,y,z):x^2+y^2\le1,z=1\}\\
&S_{\text{side}}=\{(x,y,z):x^2+y^2=1,0\le z\le1\}\\
&S_{\text{bottom}}=\{(x,y,z):x^2+y^2\le1,z=0\}\\
\end{align}
Say $S_{\text{top}}$ parametrized by a function $G:T\to S_{\text{top}}$ where $T=\{(r,\theta):0\le r\le1,0\le \theta\le2\pi\}$, such that
\begin{align}
G(r,\theta)=&(r\cos(\theta),r\sin(\theta),1)\\
\partial_1G=&(\cos(\theta),\sin(\theta),0)\\
\partial_2G=&(-\sin(\theta),\cos(\theta),0)\\
\partial_1G\times\partial_2G=&(0,0,1)
\end{align}
Therefore
\begin{align}
\iint_{S_{\text{top}}}\text{F}\cdot\text{n}dA=&\iint_T \text{F$(G(r,\theta))$}\cdot(\partial_1G\times\partial_2G)dA\\
=&\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1 \cos(\theta)r^2drd\theta\\
=&0
\end{align}
For the similar reason also have
\begin{align}
\iint_{S_{\text{bottom}}}\text{F}\cdot\text{n}dA
=&0
\end{align}
Then Integral over $S_{\text{side}}$, consider $G:T\to S_{\text{side}}$, where $T=\{(\theta,h):0\le \theta\le2\pi,0\le h\le1\}$ such that
\begin{align}
G(\theta,h)=&(\cos(\theta),\sin(\theta),h)\\
\partial_1G=&(-\sin(\theta),\cos(\theta),0)\\
\partial_2G=&(0,0,1)\\
\partial_1G\times\partial_2G=&(\cos(\theta),\sin(\theta),0)
\end{align}
Therefore
\begin{align}
\iint_{S_{\text{side}}}\text{F}\cdot\text{n}dA
=&\iint_T \text{F$(G(\theta,h))$}\cdot(\partial_1G\times\partial_2G)dhd\theta\\
=&\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1 \cos^2(\theta)\sin(\theta)+\sin^2(\theta)h~dhd\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}
\end{align}

Have $$\iint_{\partial S}\text{F}\cdot \text{n}dA=0+0+\frac{\pi}{2}=\frac{\pi}{2}$$

$(b)$ Apply divergence theorem that
\begin{align}
\iint_{\partial S}\text{F}\cdot\text{n}dA=&\iiint_S\text{div F}dV\\
=&\iiint_Sx+y+z~dV\\
=&\int_0^1\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1(r\cos(\theta)+r\sin(\theta)+z)r~drd\theta dz=\frac{\pi}{2}
\end{align}

Is my solution correct, I know if $\partial S$ oriented inwards, we can mulitply this by $-1$. However, how do I know if it has correct orientation, could someone expain this to me in details?

Comment: Yes, your answer is right, and the question says "outward orientation" so the use of divergence theorem is correct and there is no need to introduce extra minus signs. One piece of advice for the future: $\int_S x\, dV = \int_S y \, dV = 0$ by the rotational symmetry of the solid $S$ (first convince yourself intuitively then try to justify this rigorously without explicitly calculating this). So, all you're left to do is calculate $\int_S z \, dV$, and this is simple enough to calculate as $\frac{\pi}{2}$ as you have done.

Comment: $S_{Bottom}$ should be $z=0$, not $z=1$.

Comment: @Moko19 Thanks, a typo, fixed